# <> in "order by" clause causes createQuery to fail

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm on Hibernate 5.6 and want to attach this SQL order string to criteriaBuilder:

```
order by rmgtnav_path, rmgtnav_collection_type<>'PROFILE', rmgtnav_denotation asc
```

Here's the code:

```
List<Order> orderStatements = new ArrayList();

orderStatements.add(cb.asc(root.get("rmgtnav_path")));
orderStatements.add(cb.asc(cb.notEqual(root.get("rmgtnav_collection_type"), "PROFILE")));
orderStatements.add(cb.asc(root.get("rmgtnav_denotation")));


criteriQuery.orderBy(orderStatements); 

Query query = session.createQuery(cq);
```

When I call the `session.createQuery(cq)` i get the following error:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST
> node: <> near line 1, column 596 [select generatedAlias0 from
> com.myapp.core.rmgt.rate.business.object.RmgtBVOImpl
> as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.collectionType<>:param0 )
> and ( ( generatedAlias0.collectionSubType<>:param1 ) or (
> generatedAlias0.collectionSubType is null ) ) and ( (
> lower(generatedAlias0.profileStatus) like :param2 ) and ( (
> generatedAlias0.type=:param3 ) or ( generatedAlias0.type=:param4 ) ) )
> and ( generatedAlias0.enabled=:param5 ) and ( (
> generatedAlias0.owner=:param6 ) or ( generatedAlias0.owner=:param7 ) )
> order by generatedAlias0.path asc,
> generatedAlias0.collectionType<>:param8 asc,
> generatedAlias0.denotation asc]

The generated order by clause looks no different than the native SQL statement but I get this error message. Any idea how to translate this <> comparison in Order By to an expression? Looks like Hibernate is just not able to process these kinds of Expressions in orderBy segments.

In case of the WHY: I can only speculate here. The clause <> 'PROFILE' resolves to true (1) or false (0). False for values equal to 'PROFILE'. And since 0 is smaller than 1, the listing starts with 'PROFILE' and is followed by the rest.

The statement itself is valid sql:

```
SELECT rmgtnav_path, rmgtnav_denotation, rmgtnav_collection_type
FROM public.rmgt_t_navigation
order by rmgtnav_path , rmgtnav_collection_type, rmgtnav_denotation asc
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Whereas:

```
SELECT rmgtnav_path, rmgtnav_denotation, rmgtnav_collection_type
FROM public.rmgt_t_navigation
order by rmgtnav_path , rmgtnav_collection_type <> 'PROFILE', rmgtnav_denotation asc
```

[image: ![![enter image description here]

And as a second question, is there any way of removing the asc tags from the generated code when I don't need them, like in the original sql?

Comment: asc is default. It doesn't matter if it's there or not and you cannot remove it
JPA does not support <> in order by. If you want to use this you have to use SQL

Comment: You cannot use a conditional in an order by statement, eg `rmgtnav_collection_type<>'PROFILE'` is simply not valid. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use conventional SQL. Change:

```
rmgtnav_collection_type<>'PROFILE'
```

to:

```
case when rmgtnav_collection_type = 'PROFILE' then 0 else 1 end
```

Swap `0` and `1` (or add `DESC`) if you want the reverse order.

Comment: That would work but I'm lookin for a solution in combination with CriteriaBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a case expression for this purpose:

```
orderStatements.add(
    cb.asc(
        cb.selectCase()
            .when(
                cb.notEqual(root.get("rmgtnav_collection_type"), "PROFILE"),
                cb.literal(0)
            )
            .otherwise(cb.literal(1))
    )
);
```